# Expresso Store Discount Dates

Tags: expresso-store, checkout, discounts

I cannot get the start and end dates of my discount to save. I enter them, hit save, and then when it returns me to the list of discounts, the dates are no longer there. The code does not work on the site without the dates entered. I have other discounts that are active and their dates have saved without a problem. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: It is always good to include the version numbers of EE and Store that you are using so we can rule out any possible bugs.

Comment: Hi @Mike, did you resolve this issue?